# optimize search through parameter space to find parameters sets

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have a simulation which calculates the amount of time it takes for a tank/tube to drop below a certain temperature, given a set of parameters. 
The simulation takes quite a while to run and I would like to find out which sets of parameters(atm 4) give a 2 hour result (ie temperature drops below threshold after two hours).

At first I was considering using RSM (response surface methodology) to create a model of the parameter space. However, I really want to search around and for parameters which result in 2 hours and not the entire space.

I was also considering using a linear programming solver, However I do not want to optimize to a single value, I need to optimize to a 'curve' of potential values.

Is there a methodology which combines RSM and linprog. or another alternative to figure optimally which parameter sets can be used to give a particular result?

thanks!

Comment: I am not sure, are you looking for something like [Kriging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriging)?

Comment: Kriging sounds interesting, however I do not want sample the result over all values of the parameters, I want to have parameter selection guided to minimize trial runs

Comment: That is what Kriging about. You optimize based on a model to get a new trial parameter set. Evaluate/simulate it. Use the result to improve the model.

Comment: could you provide a paper or example where Kirging can be used like this? or a software package? I find only 2D examples and libraries. It does seem like this is what i am looking for

Comment: kriging is well known. just google for it. mostly it appears in context of geo science.